# Problem installing Asterisk on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: drivers, compiling, asterisk

First, the card A200 from Sangoma is detected... lspci does list the card.

For installation, I followed the instructions at http://wiki.sangoma.com/wanpipe-linux-asterisk-dahdi.

All was well until I reached "Sangoma Driver Installation."
Even here, it was all smooth until I reached "Select option 2 to install the Wanpipe driver for Asterisk."

During compilation, here are the errors I got:

```
================== START OF DISPLAY after entering option 2 ==================================

Please select (1-7) [Default: 1]: 2

Looking for zaptel/dahdi directory in /usr/src ...
-------------------------------------------
1 : /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.10.0.1+2.10.0.1
------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------
m : Enter zaptel path manually

(ctrl-c to Exit)
Please select working zaptel directory [1-1][m]: 1

Enabling the TDM Voice Asterisk Support

Dahdi HW HDLC Support Detected: Enabling DCHAN Feature
Native Dahdi HW HDLC Support Detected - No patch required
Dahdi source unmodified

Checking for UDEV Zaptel compatibility... Dahdi installed, no need to add UDEV rules
Enabling the AFT TE1 Support

Checking for SMP support ...Enabled.

Checking current processor type ...i686

Checking fo regparm: Disabled


--------------------------------------------------
CFLAGS: gcc -Wp,-MD,.wanpipe.o.d -nostdinc -iwithprefix include -D__LINUX__ -Dlinux  -D__KERNEL__ -I/usr/include/wanpipe -I/lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/build/include -DMODULE
--------------------------------------------------

Compiling General WANPIPE Driver for 3.X.X Kernel .
---------------------------------------------


WANPIPE DRIVER COMPILE LOG
Thu Mar 26 22:16:39 IST 2015
-----------------------------------
make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/build SUBDIRS=/usr/src/wanpipe-7.0.12/kdrvtmp CC=gcc KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic'
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || ( \
echo >&2; \
echo >&2 " ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid."; \
echo >&2 " include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 " Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it."; \
echo >&2 ; \
/bin/false)
mkdir -p /usr/src/wanpipe-7.0.12/kdrvtmp/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /usr/src/wanpipe-7.0.12/kdrvtmp/.tmp_versions/*
make -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=/usr/src/wanpipe-7.0.12/kdrvtmp 
gcc -Wp,-MD,/usr/src/wanpipe-7.0.12/kdrvtmp/.sdladrv_src.o.d -nostdinc -isystem 

/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/include -I./arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include
/generated -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi 

-I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h 

-Iubuntu/include -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs 

-fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format 

-security -m32 -msoft-float -mregparm=3 -freg-struct-return -mno-mmx -mno-sse-fno-pic 

-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i686 -mtune=generic -maccumulate-outgoing-args 

-Wa,-mtune=generic32 -ffreestanding -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 

-DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CRC32=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 

-pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 

-mno-3dnow -mno-avx -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 

-fstack-protector -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize 

sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -Wdeclaration-after-statement 

-Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -Werror=implicit-int 

-Werror=strict-prototypes -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -D__LINUX__-DCONFIG_PRODUCT_WANPIPE_BASE 

-DCONFIG_PRODUCT_WANPIPE_TDM_VOICE -DCONFIG_PRODUCT_WANPIPE_TDM_VOICE_DCHAN-DDAHDI_210 

-DCONFIG_PRODUCT_WANPIPE_TDM_VOICE_DCHAN_ZAPTEL -DDAHDI_ISSUES 

-DCONFIG_PRODUCT_WANPIPE_AFT -DCONFIG_PRODUCT_WANPIPE_AFT_CORE 

-DCONFIG_PRODUCT_WANPIPE_AFT_TE1 -DCONFIG_PRODUCT_WANPIPE_AFT_56K 

-DCONFIG_PRODUCT_WANPIPE_AFT_RM -DCONFIG_PRODUCT_WANPIPE_CODEC_SLINEAR_LAW 

-DCONFIG_PRODUCT_WANPIPE_AFT_BRI -DCONFIG_PRODUCT_WANPIPE_AFT_SERIAL 

-DCONFIG_PRODUCT_WANPIPE_AFT_A600 -DCONFIG_PRODUCT_WANPIPE_AFT_B601 

-DCONFIG_PRODUCT_WANPIPE_AFT_B800 -DCONFIG_PRODUCT_WANPIPE_AFT_A700 

-DCONFIG_PRODUCT_WANPIPE_USB -DWANPIPE_USE_I_PRIVATE -DKERN_PROC_PDE_FEATURE=1 

-DKERN_SK_FOR_NODE_FEATURE=0 -DCONFIG_WANPIPE_HWEC -I//usr/include/wanpipe -I/usr/include

/wanpipe/oct6100_api -I/usr/include/wanpipe/oct6100_api/include -I/usr/include/wanpipe

/oct6100_api/include/oct6100api -DMODULE -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" 

-D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(sdladrv_src)" -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(sdladrv)" -c -o 

/usr/src/wanpipe-7.0.12/kdrvtmp/.tmp_sdladrv_src.o /usr/src/wanpipe-7.0.12/kdrvtm/sdladrv_src.c
/usr/src/wanpipe-7.0.12/kdrvtmp/sdladrv_src.c: In function âsdla_hw_bridge_probeâ:
/usr/src/wanpipe-7.0.12/kdrvtmp/sdladrv_src.c:3942:3: error: implicit declaration of function âpci_bus_bâ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
bus = pci_bus_b(pci_dev->bus->children.next);
^
/usr/src/wanpipe-7.0.12/kdrvtmp/sdladrv_src.c:3942:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
bus = pci_bus_b(pci_dev->bus->children.next);
^
/usr/src/wanpipe-7.0.12/kdrvtmp/sdladrv_src.c:3951:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
bus = pci_bus_b(pci_dev->bus->children.prev);
^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/wanpipe-7.0.12/kdrvtmp/sdladrv_src.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/usr/src/wanpipe-7.0.12/kdrvtmp] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2

---------------------------------------------

=========================== END OF DISPLAY ================================
```

So, what is the problem? Why am I getting these errors? I think that there are some incompatibility issues between the latest DAHDI library and the latest Wanpipe drivers. Anyone found the corrections and compatible versions of these two which work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

support[at]sangoma.com:

"... the new kernel you're using did brake our wanpipe driver."

"The R&D will be relaseing a new version, I believe within two weeks or so."

Comment: Did you receive those information from the original support address of Sangoma? If yes, please clarify this and _explain_ instead of just dumping two quotes.. Otherwise your post could also be downvoted for too less detail or spam or whatever. Thank you for participating on AskUbuntu and making the internet a better place. :-)

Comment: This is the first time I, or anyone in my team, is getting this info.  Could you please clarify where your quotes are coming from, which version of Ubuntu it applies to, etc.? We tried different versions of the Wanpipe drivers but to no avail. Its comforting to know that the problem is on the Sangoma end and that they are doing something about it.  As for the details in my post, they would be required for anyone to understand the problem, or so I think.  THANKS.

Comment: Was there a solution found? I am having the same problem on the same version of Ubuntu.